# How to change orientation of video in project?

Tags: premiere

How to set this video to be horizontal, not vertical? Using Adobe Premiere 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the aspect ratio of your width/height. Your current aspect ratio looks like 9:16, so probably 1080:1920 in pixels. Change this to 16:9, meaning 1920:1080. You can find these settings in the sequence settings of your sequence.